# Supertest not returning correct status

Tags: express, supertest

Having an issue getting supertest to assert the proper status response.  **What am I doing wrong?**

```
/// server.js /////
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.status(200).json({ message: 'v1.0' });
});


// test.js ////
it('should fail but passes', function(done) {
    request
        .get('/')
        .expect(500, done);
});
```

Comment: have you looked into co-mocha? I am using it for testing with promises.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/co-mocha

Comment: @AndyMacleod I'm actually using jasmine

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was due to the use of jasmine.  Apparently the `done()` function in jasmine supersedes the done function in supertest so you have to handle the error in an `end()` method.

https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-npm/issues/31

```
it('should fail & does', function(done) {
    request
        .get('/doesNotExist')
        .expect(200)
        .end(function(err, res) {
            if (err) {
                done.fail(err);
            } else {
                done();
            }
        });
});
```